# Matching combinations of 8 columns selected from 10 columns (graph theory)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am not studying maths and so do not ahve any background on which to comprehend statistics and mathematics, it's also been 20 years since I studied it.  I'm doing some research for a graph database application and am trying to calculate the number of edges(relationships) that will be created when matching combinations of  8 columns from a table of 10 columns, with varying different numbers of rows

Columns A to F are [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Columns G and H are [1, 2, 3]
Columns I and J are [1, 2]

I know in total there are in total 562,500 permutations but I'm trying to find out how many times 8 out of the 10 can be combined:

X,Y,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1;
X,1,Y,1,1,1,1,1,1,1;

*through to*

5,5,5,5,5,5,3,X,2,Y;
5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,X,Y;

where X and Y are any number from the column.

Need to work this out so that we can accurately calculate the hardware requirements for the application.

Thank you in advance to anyone who is able to help, I have tried to find the answer but I only find regular permutation questions and answers.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what is being asked here.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to create a graph database, where each vertex is a permutation of the available responses to 10 questions.  Think of each column A-J as a question. the arrays I listed are the possible responses to each question, so A-F: 5 answers, G- H: 3, I-J: 2 answers

I am trying to find out how many edges (combinations) there will be if I matched each vertex by only 8 of the 10 responses to the questionnaire  for example

Vertex (Response) 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1  will match to 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2; 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2; 1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2..all the way to..... 5,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1;

Comment: Would breaking it down this way be right?

(CR(5,6)) * (CR(3,2)) * (CR(2,2))

Comment: My best bet would be to use the fact that the sum of the degrees of each vertex is twice the number of edges.

Comment: But how do I calculate the number of edges?

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out a different way, painstakingly went through and created each possible matching combination to

1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1

which gave me 405 matches, I then used a series calculator to give me

sum_(n=1)^405 n^2 = 22,225,455

This process has helped me in creating the script for generating the relationships, which will need to be created in batches.  But would like to know if there is a more efficient way to calculate this incase we decide to scale the number of questions up